# WebAuthenticationBroker equivalent in android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am developing a cross platform android application on Visual Studio 2013. I already have developed a Windows store app where I have used `WebAuthenticationBroker` to start a asynchronous authentication process. I wanted to know if there is anything equivalent to this that I can use in android.

Here is my Windows store app code:-

```
 var broker = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, endUri);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin for development, you can find the answer in this related question: [WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync in android Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031990/webauthenticationbroker-authenticateasync-in-android-xamarin)