# WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync in android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Iam developing a cross platform android app using Xamarin. Currently I am stuck with the `WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync` method and cannot find anything equivalent to it.

Here is something I want to do in android:

```
       var broker = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, startUri, endUri);

            var datax = broker.ResponseData;
            if (broker.ResponseStatus != WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
                await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Invalid username or user doesn't exists").ShowAsync();
```

According to the documentation there is no `WebAuthenticationBroker` in xamarin as of now. Is there any work around for achieving the same?
Any ideas how this can be achieved with android in xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [Xamarin.Auth](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth)? It seems like that's what you want. Here is a little code snippet which would give you a hint about what you can do with it:

```
using Xamarin.Auth;
...
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
    clientId: "App ID from https://developers.facebook.com/apps",
    scope: "",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));
```

The callback event:

```
auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    // We presented the UI, so it's up to us to dimiss it on iOS.
    DismissViewController (true, null);

    if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
        // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
    } else {
        // The user cancelled
    }
};
```